# Ajax 405 (Method Not Allowed) Cross Domain Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to run this script from localhost but it gets an error **405 (Method Not Allowed)** .

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://some.url/',
        type:'post',
        //crossDomain: true,
        data:'{id:"49"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:'jsonp',

            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('right');
                var value = responseData.someKey;
                console.log(value);
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");  
            }
    });
});
```

I have tried with `crossDomain:true` and `$.support.cors = true`, but of no use.Any ideas?

Comment: Does the actual server return the proper CORS headers? Setting those attributes only makes it check for these headers.

Comment: Because http://54.200.58.88:8080/companyservice/methodName?callback=jQuery19109528355574429344_1384847320058&id=49&_=1384847320059 is not responding

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy   I cant access to server code.How to check it?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar Thanks .Updated the url now.I had put a dummy url earlier.

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing to do with CORS, HTTP 405 means that your HTTP method is not permitted, e.g. GET, POST, etc.

According to Chrome dev tools, only POST and OPTIONS are permitted HTTP methods.

[image: Chrome dev tools response headers]

To send a POST request using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), use the following:

```
$.ajax('url', {
    // other settings here
    type: 'POST'
}
```

You can also use the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) wrapper method to do the same thing.

**Note that the particular site in question has not setup cross-origin support, therefore if you need to access this, you'll need to get the site to fix this issue or you'll need to use your server as a proxy.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What is reverse proxy the request??