# How to do a jQuery GET request to a cross domain WSSE REST web-service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, wsse

I'm stuck with a CORS problem. 
I have developed a REST webservice using WSSE to secure it. The webservice has to be called from an hybrid mobile application throught a jQuery request.

I'm trying to call the webservice methods via jquery but I got always a 405 response.

This is the virtual host configuration:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *    
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

This is the jQuery client:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        beforeSend : function(xhrObj) {
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader(
                    "Authorization",'WSSE profile="UsernameToken"'
            );
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader(
                    "X-WSSE", generateWsseToken(username, secret)
            );
        },
        url: callUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

These are response and request as shown in Firebug:

```
-- RESPONSE --
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 13:46:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6
Cache-Control: no-cache

Allow: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

-- REQUEST --
OPTIONS /myurl HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.66
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-wsse
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I have read many discussions but withouth luck. For instance:

- [Ajax 405 (Method Not Allowed) Cross Domain Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065932/ajax-405-method-not-allowed-cross-domain-issue),
- http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/,
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/,
- [How do CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Headers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work)

Comment: In cross domai `jsonp` is used: ``dataType: "jsonp"``

Comment: If I understand right, jsonp doesn't permit to add custom headers to the HTTP request but I need them for WSSE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073287/set-headers-with-jquery-ajax-and-jsonp

Comment: i don't know about that but cross domain will not work with json you have to use jsonp

Comment: This is a bad situation. Using jsonp I can't send WSSE headers but using JSON I can't make cross domain requests. How to manage this? I could modify the webservice but this is not properly convenient...